# Load all the data first not while scrolling horizontally in jQWidget jQX grid

Tags: jquery, scroll, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I am using JQWidget JQX grid. In the grid I have one horizontal scroll, now I need to d some task whenever user scroll horizontally. Is there any way we can do this? I have tried so many things like we do normal scrolls  https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/ , still no luck. In the grid the horizontal data is populated whenever user scrolls horizontally dynamically even if I have assigned the full source. The rows gets appended to the div 'contenttablejqxgrid' only when user scrolls.

[image]

[image]

Now is there any property to make sure the grid loads all the data in the page instead creating while scrolling? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please post a full minimal example, if you expect serious help.

There is no scroll event from jqx-grid (at least not for horizontal scroll) and usually, it is not needed to care about what you are describing. What exactly is your problem and what do you want to do while the horizontal scrollbar is used?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to utilize the an event listener of some sort. 
In JQ you're going to do something like this:

```
$("#yourDiv").bind("pagechanged", function (event) {
    event.whatever
    Do something cool    
})
```